# private internal maven repository

Tags: maven-2, repository

I wonder whether I can setting up a private maven repository based on my svn. 
The svn can be accessed via http.

If yes, then what should I do? Just uploading the architypes is enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If yes, then what should I do? Just uploading the architypes is enough?

While subversion is not really made for that, yes, Maven can deploy through WebDAV so it is possible (a lot of people are actually doing this for their google-code projects).

If you want to set this up for an existing maven project (and have the created artifacts deployed to your SNV repository during the `deploy` phase), adapt the solution described in [Hosting a Maven repository on Google Code](http://www.beeworks.be/hosting-maven-repository-google-code/).

If you just want to add a particular artifacts, use the `deploy:deploy-file` goal:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
    -DrepositoryId="internal" \
    -Durl="dav:https://server/repo" \
    -Dfile="some-jar.jar" \
    -DgroupId="my.groupid" \
    -DartifactId="my-artifactid" \
    -Dversion="1.2.3" \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -DgeneratePom=true
```

Under GNU/Linux, you can paste this command as is; under Windows, run it on one line without the `\`.

Answer (score 1):

The question shouldn't be can you but should you. Yes you can. No you shouldn't. Instead of using a tool designed to manage source diffs for binary storage, instead get an artifact repository manager like [Nexus](https://nexus.codehaus.org/index.html) to manage the binaries. Repository managers have tons of features designed especially to host, share, promote, secure binaries that you don't find in a typical scm. For example an scm has no capability to appropriately deal with maven snapshots.

If you want more information about why you should use a repository manager, take a look at the documents [here](http://www.sonatype.com/products/nexus/intro).

Comment: Nexus documentation URL is not working anymore, the updated URL should be http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/intro.html